# Reading separated data into an array structure c++

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to read data separated by ';' into an array of structure, so I can later filter them.
Example data:

```
1.1 ; name1; 11-07-2014; 14:30
1.2 ; name2; 11-07-2017; 15:10
```

I don't know how many entries will be in this .txt file. Also I need to add a posibility to choose with which file user wants to work (that works) I'm new in c++ so I would be gratefull for any tips.

So far I've created this:

```
typedef struct{
    char numb[21];
    char names[100];
    char date[11];
    char time[6];
}vec;

vec *logs[200];

void_fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    char fname[MAX_PATH] ="";
    ZeroMemory( & ofn, sizeof( ofn ) );
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof( ofn );
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All files\0*.*\0";
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrFile = fname;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = "txt";
    ofn.Flags = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;

    string line;

    if( GetOpenFileName( & ofn ) )
    {
        for(int i=0; i<200; i++){
            getline(fname, logs[i].numb, ';');
            getline(fname, logs[i].names, ';');
            getline(fname, logs[i].date, ';');
            getline(fname, logs[i].time, ';');   
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error 
E2285 Could not find a match for 'getline<_CharT,_Traits,_Alloc>(char *,undefined,char)'

Comment: Read an entire line using `getline`. Then, inside that line, find the semicolons.

Comment: `logs` is an array of `vec *` but you're not using the correct operator. You should be using `logs[i]->numb`. Secondly, you're using `std::getline` incorrectly (assuming that's what it is.) There's no overload that takes a `char[]` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your code. `fname` is a LPTSTR, so a string. How is that supposed to work with getline?

The only get line functions I know is either:

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
ssize_t getdelim(char **lineptr, size_t *n, int delim, FILE *stream);
```

or:

```
std::istream& std::getline(std::istream& is, std::string& str, char delim);
std::istream& std::getline(std::istream& is, std::string& str);
```

And since you use `GetOpenFileName` you are on windows, which means that you can only use the later. No matter, you need to actually open a file for reading.

How about:

```
struct vec{
    std::string numb;
    std::string names;
    std::string date;
    std::string time;
};

std::vector<vec> logs;

size_t i = 0;
std::ifstream in(fname);
while (in.good() && i < 200)
{
    std::string line;
    getline(in, line);

    std::vector<std::string> bits = explode(line, ";");
    assert(bits.size() == 4);
    vec v = {bits[0], bits[1], bits[2], bits[3]};
    logs.push_back(v);        
    i++;
}
```

And here is my handy explode function:

```
std::vector<std::string> explode(const std::string& str, const std::string& delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> gibs;
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t end = 0;

    while ((start != std::string::npos) && (start < str.size()))
    {
        end = str.find(delimiter, start);

        std::string gib;
        if (end == std::string::npos)
        {
            gib = str.substr(start);
            start = std::string::npos;
        }
        else
        {
            gib = str.substr(start, end - start);
            start = end + delimiter.size();
        }
        gibs.push_back(gib);
    }

    return gibs;
}
```

Finally make up your mind if you want to program C or C++. Mixing both is never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one more question. There is an error which I can't resolve in line: 
logs.push_back({bits[0], bits[1], bits[2], bits[3]});
I know that this line is required to add new elements, but program only compile, when I comment it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the code was wrong there. You can not build a struct "inline" in a function call. I fixed the code, by building the struct explicitly and then adding it to the vector.

Comment: I tried this way (first changed {} bracekts to () ) but there's still an error: cannot convert 'string' to 'vec'.

Comment: This is the line I changed: `vec v = {bits[0], bits[1], bits[2], bits[3]};` and that should work.

Comment: Ok, it's not working, but maybe that's because I use borland builder. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: No it was an oversight of mine; I did not compile the code and I programmed to much JavaScript lately.